# Dudas con el ámbito de las variables

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un lector de datos en JavaScript. Se trata de leer un archivo de texto (.txt) que se encuentra en el equipo del usuario. Leo el archivo completo y con expresiones regulares extraigo la información que necesito.

El problema es que no veo claro el ámbito de las variables. Declaro todas las variables al principio del script:

```
var description='';
var adjustment='';
...
```

Después leo el archivo .txt y asigno el contenido a una variable `reader` y continúo extrayendo los datos que quiero con expresiones regulares a `reader` pero no consigo asignar el resultado de la expresión regular a la variable arriba declarada.

Lo tengo hecho en Python y a cada resultado de la expresión regular lo asigno a la variable que quiero. Después compongo un PDF con los resultados. En JavaScript no lo consigo porque me deja las variables vacías.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Éste es mi código:

```
function processFiles(files) { 
    file = files[0]; 
    reader = new FileReader(); 

    reader.onload = function (e) { 
        output = document.getElementById("fileOutput"); 
        output.textContent = e.target.result; 
        resultados_texto = output.textContent; 
        console.log(resultados_texto); 
    }; 

    reader.readAsText(file); 
    // resultados_texto=output.textContent; 
    re = /Name:(.*)/gm; 
    var m; 
    while ((m = re.exec(resultados_texto)) !== null) { 
        if (m.index === re.lastIndex) { 
            re.lastIndex++; 
        } 

        console.log(m[1]); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hola, creo que en este caso seria ideal tener el código javascript  y python para poder observar mejor que esta pasando.

Comment: function processFiles(files) {
 file = files[0];
 reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = function (e) 
 {

 output = document.getElementById("fileOutput");
 output.textContent = e.target.result;
 resultados_texto = output.textContent;
 console.log(resultados_texto);
 };
 reader.readAsText(file);
 // resultados_texto=output.textContent;

  re = /Name:(.*)/gm; 
  var m;
 
  while ((m = re.exec(resultados_texto)) !== null) {
      if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
          re.lastIndex++;
      }
      console.log(m[1]);
  }

}

Comment: m devuelve undefined en la consola

Answer (score 3):

El problema del código en JavaScript (por el que `m` devuelve `undefined`) se debe a que la variable nunca se instancia/inicializa a ningún valor.

Esto ocurre porque **se está asignando un valor de manera síncrona, pero el valor se obtiene de una variable que se declara/asigna de manera asíncrona** (`onload` se ejecuta asíncronamente). Por eso, se corre el riesgo de que la "variable asíncrona" (`resultados_texto`) no se haya inicializado y no tenga ningún valor.

La solución sería mover la parte del código que utiliza `resultados_texto` (en la que se le asigna un valor a `m`) a dentro del método `onload` del reader. Algo como esto:

```
function processFiles(files) { 
    file = files[0]; 
    reader = new FileReader(); 

    reader.onload = function (e) { 
        output = document.getElementById("fileOutput"); 
        output.textContent = e.target.result; 
        resultados_texto = output.textContent; 
        console.log(resultados_texto); 

        // Aquí resultados_texto ya tiene valor; 
        re = /Name:(.*)/gm; 
        var m; 
        while ((m = re.exec(resultados_texto)) !== null) { 
            if (m.index === re.lastIndex) { 
                re.lastIndex++; 
            }

            console.log(m[1]); 
        } 
    }; 

    reader.readAsText(file); 
}
```

De este modo `resultados_texto` ya tendrá un valor y `m = re.exec(resultados_texto)` debería funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: Gracias. Iré probando. Me parece que tengo mucho que aprender. Vengo de Python pero esto es otra cosa.

Comment: ¿Cómo se ejecuta de forma asíncrona si Javascript se ejecuta en un único hilo?

Comment: @dwarandae Un único hilo no significa que no pueda ser asíncrono. No es lo mismo sincronismo (ejecutar las instrucciones en orden) y concurrencia (ejecutar más de una instrucción al mismo tiempo). JavaScript tiene un único hilo pero puede ejecutar funciones de forma asíncrona en diferentes modos. El ejemplo más extendido es AJAX, pero también puede darse en otras situaciones como los Promises o, el caso de la pregunta, la API FileReader, que lee asíncronamente el fichero y lanza el evento `onload` cuando la carga termina

Comment: Y hay alguna otra manera mas fácil de 'leer' un archivo que se encuentre en el equipo local y meterlo en una variable su contenido ?

Comment: @kamome hay métodos específicos para ciertos navegadores o bajando los niveles de seguridad, pero no creo que sean recomendables (a no ser que tengas control sobre los navegadores que el cliente usará y puede que ni siquiera así)